# How to deploy files to Azure Web App Service with Azure REST API?

Tags: azure, rest, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to automate my building and deployment process, and what I want to do is to deploy some files to Azure Web App Service by using [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps)

I see the list of possible actions, but can't really find a request that sends files to Azure. To make the story short, I have a folder with files, and I need to deploy it to Azure with a Shell-script, or some other script (but not manually).

Is there a way to do this? If yes, I would be graceful to consider some examples of code. Thanks.

Comment: Have you gone through this document--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#deploy-individual-files

Answer (score 0):

Deploy a startup script, library, and static file to your web app by using the  [az webapp deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp#az-webapp-deploy)  command with the  `--type`  parameter.

If you deploy a startup script this way, App Service automatically uses your script to start your app.

```
az webapp deploy --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --src-path scripts/startup.sh --type=startup
```

for complete information you can refer this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#deploy-individual-files).

Comment: Well I was hoping to see a REST API solution, not Azure CLI. That's the point of my question.